# Are shoes comparable to capacitors if receiving electric shock from one lead?

Tags: ground, earth

I seem to not totally understand the way how we can receive an electric shock when touching only one lead of a general power outlet (230VAC):

1. Are our shoes/wooden floor/concrete like a capacitor which can conduct AC?
2. Is there current flow between the ground of the secondary, provided it is connected to some good ground rod and a persons feet or do we 'agree' on the idea that the earth just has so many loose electrons such that two different earthing places exist?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fyO059.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Shoes aren't generally designed to be non-conductive. Sure they're not *good* conductors, but they're not designed to meet any standards of electrical safety. Also, you're using that isolation transformer wrong.

Comment: I know I shouldn't reference it to earth, yes, I just wanted to draw the situation as it is.

Comment: I didn't try this, but I expect my multimeter to show infinite resistance when I put one lead on the inside bottom of my shoe and the other one at the outside bottom... Measuring the sole's resistance.

Comment: When working with high voltages, things work differently due to things like dielectric breakdown. Your multimeter will only test at a handful of volts, maybe 3~9 volts. Devices made for testing insulation safety (commonly known as "meggers" after a popular brand, or "hi-pot testers") will do the same tests, but at hundreds or thousands of volts.

Comment: That is very interesting :)

Comment: Have you ever seen a bird sitting on a power wire?  Why isn't that bird smoking?

Comment: Yeah I know about the birds :) I just wonder how the in-earth current flow is seen in our earth-being-ground theories

Answer (score 2):

> 1. Are our shoes/wooden floor/concrete like a capacitor which can conduct AC?

Yes, they can be considered as a capacitor with negligible capacitance.

> 2. Is there current flow between the ground of the secondary...

The isolation transformer is connected with the idea of ​​not being connected to the ground.

Comment: Answer to question 2: Yes I know, see my comment, this is just for testing/understanding the situation.

Comment: Answer to question 1: Does this negligable capacitance mean it conduct 50Hz AC quite well, or should I not see it this way?

Comment: @Niels, I've touched the line with my bare hand with shoes on and stepped on a wooden floor... I even made a video... but I don't recommend it for beginners.  If you do decide to do it, hold your other hand behind your back.

Comment: I am only interested in the theory. I am not about to touch anything :)

Comment: Even if you are floating in the middle of a room, you would still be a big blob of electrically conducting liquids and you would have stray capacitances to earth and surrounding electrically conductive structures and even if those structures are not directly connected to earth they have capacitance to other electrically conductive structures that might be connected to earth. This is just simplified as having a human with stray capacitance of few pF to earth.

Comment: @Circuitfantasist I wouldn't recommend that for experts either. If you want to make a video to make a point for educational purposes, and you know what you're doing, alright, but I still wouldn't recommend it!

Comment: So @justme what about the capacitance when you're just standing on the floor. Would it conduct AC at 50 Hz as we say? That being the reason we can get a shock this way...

Comment: @Hearth, I hid the link to the video from my students and promised to show them when they become engineers :-)